# i wanna count the number of player which is in ACDFGH. In Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, count

Here is a sample document. I need to count the number of Players with the name "ACDFGH". Can anyone guide me please?

```
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5f040b9dd956a3109ec7d839"),
        "Name" : "ACDFGH",
        "Publisher" : "adasdhd Co., Ltd.",
        "Released" : "April 5,1920",
        "Ratting" : 99,
        "Country" : "UK",
        "Address" : "694 Hewes Street",
        "Player" : [ 
            {
                "Name" : "Derrick",
                "Goal" : 705
            }, 
            {
                "Name" : "Tim",
                "Goal" : 379
            }, 
            {
                "Name" : "Bryan",
                "Goal" : 810
            }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). The pipeline would look like this in the mongo shell:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "Name": "ACDFGH" }},
  { $project: { "playerCount" : { $size: "$Player" }}}
])
```

This will give you the document with just the `_id` field and a  `playerCount` field. If you want all the other fields and the `playerCount`, you can replace the `$project` with `$set`.